# how to seed multiple id's for one parameter under a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, seeding

I've been struggling with the modeling and the initial seed process of this app for a while now. I wanted to make a joint table `EventArtist` between `Event` and `Artist` so that it would be possible to retrieve all the artists that are on any event's lineup and all the events an artists has taken part in. How do I add multiple `artist_id`s to one event?

here is the seed file:

```
venue = Venue.create(name: "Speakeasy", address: "Lynwood Ave", zip_code: "30312")
artist = Artist.create(name: "DJ Sliink", bio: "jersey club king")
artist2 = Artist.create(name: "DJ Spinn", bio: "Teklife's chief spokesperson")
#this is probably wrong
lineup = EventArtist.create({artist_id: artist.id}, {artist_id: artist2.id})

event = Event.create(name: "Dance your ass off", 
                      date: DateTime.new(2016,2,3,10,0,0,'+7'), 
                      venue: venue, 
                      #this right here... how?
                      artist_id: , 
                      description: "free free free")
```

here are relevant parts of the schema

```
  create_table "event_artist", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "artist_id"
    t.integer "event_id"
  end

  add_index "event_artist", ["artist_id"], name: "index_event_artist_on_artist_id", using: :btree
  add_index "event_artist", ["event_id"], name: "index_event_artist_on_event_id", using: :btree

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "venue_id"
  end

  add_index "events", ["venue_id"], name: "index_events_on_venue_id", using: :btree
```

the models:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :venue
  has many :artists, through :event_artists
end

class EventArtist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, through: :event_artists
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this to both models:

```
has_many :event_artists
```

The models were so:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :venue
  has_many :artists, through: :event_artists
  has_many :event_artists
end

class EventArtist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, through: :event_artists
  has_many :event_artists
end
```

So you can seed:

```
event = Event.create(name: "Dance your ass off", 
                      date: DateTime.new(2016,2,3,10,0,0,'+7'), 
                      venue: venue, 
                      artists: [artist, artist2], 
                      description: "free free free")
```

or

```
event = Event.create(name: "Dance your ass off", 
                      date: DateTime.new(2016,2,3,10,0,0,'+7'), 
                      venue: venue,  
                      description: "free free free")
event.artists << artist
event.artists << artist2
```

Both will work. Good Luck ;)

Comment: how does the `EventArtist` play into this, though?

Comment: You need to add has_many :event_artists to both models. I edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that Artists are associated with Events by creating EventArtists, not by adding artist_id to Event.

First, we need to declare that an Event has EventArtists. Add has_many :event_artists to your Event model.

In your seed file, get rid of the artist_id when creating an event.

```
event = Event.create(name: "Dance your ass off", 
                  date: DateTime.new(2016,2,3,10,0,0,'+7'), 
                  venue: venue, 
                  description: "free free free")
```

You can associate an artist with that event by creating an EventArtist

```
EventArtist.create(event_id: event.id, artist_id: artist.id)
```

Since rails knows the association between events, event_artists, and artists, all of the following do the same thing:

```
event.event_artists.create({artist_id: artist.id}, {artist_id: artist2.id})
event.event_artists.create({artist: artist}, {artist: artist2})
artist.event_artists.create({event_id: event.id})
artist.event_artists.create({event: event})
```

Now you can do things like

```
lineup = event.artists
```

- or -

```
artist_events = artist.events
```

Comment: this sound like it should work, but I get this error now `syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
  has many :artists, through :event_artists`

Comment: oh wait, that must be because I'm missing a `:` in the model file

Comment: forgot to mention you'll also need to add has_many :event_artists to Event. edited my answer.

Comment: `undefined method 'event_artist'` :(

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, will play around and give an update

Comment: try event.event_artists (plural)

Comment: the problem was that I named the join table `event_artist` singular to begin with, not plural. so I changed it to plural. however, this way still does not work: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)`. if I do it individually, like `EventArtist.create({artist_id = artist.id}, {event_id = event.id})`, then it seems to store into db.

Comment: choosing the other answer as the correct solution since it works with the exact code that it offers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an individual record for each artist in EventArtist. Since you have a has_many through association this will allow you to say `event.artists` and return all the artists in that event. But each one needs it's own EventArtist record with one `artist_id` and the `event_id`

You also need to create the `Event` before creating any of the `EventArtist`s